# Sub-document in an array saves as an empty array item if no value is provided on document creation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What I want is for a particular field in my schema to be an array with items in it.

When I create the document in question, I will not have any array items. Therefore, I expect my document to look like:

```
{
  notes: []
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting an array that looks like:

```
{
  notes: ['']
}
```

Querying the `notes.length`, I get 1, which is problematic for me, because it's essentially an empty array item.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
const SubDocumentSchema = function () {
  return new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  })
}

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    notes: {
      type: [SubDocumentSchema()]
    }
});

const Document = mongooseConnection.model('DocumentSchema', DocumentSchema)
const t = new Document()

t.save()
```

Comment: What is `NotesSchema`? Not in your code. It also probably should be `type: [NotesSchema]` since the `()` implies invoking a function, not assigning a "schema type" as you should be doing here.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that. I actually changed the schema to just `new....` without being returned from a function, but I'm still get an array with an empty first value. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Again you don't do `new`. Just do it like I already ( and as the documentation also does ) showed you. `type: [SubDocumentSchema]`. No `new` and no brackets `()`. You use it there just like the second argument in your `mongoose.model` call `.model('DocumentSchema', DocumentSchema)` where again, no `new` and no brackets `()`.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but the Mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) do specify instantiating a new schema sub-doc.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. `const SubDocumentSchema = new Schema({ ...` It's the same for "all schema" whether it's the root of the model, or in an array or just a property. So no `function()`, no returning a function and certainly no invoking. The "invocation" is actually what is creating the "empty string". See also https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify empty array as the default value for notes. And you don't need to return a function for the SubDocumentSchema. Try the below edited code.

```
const SubDocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  notes: {
    type: [SubDocumentSchema],
    default: []
  }
});

const Document = mongooseConnection.model('DocumentSchema', DocumentSchema)
const t = new Document()

t.save()
```